# Evaluate the following limit using L'Hopitals rule

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\left(\frac{8}{x}-\sin\frac{8}{x}\right)$

In this current form the limit is ${0 * \infty}$ How would I go about getting the proper indeterminate form so that L'Hopitals rule is applicable?

Comment: Write it as $$f(x)\cdot g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1/g(x)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{8/x- \sin (8/x)}{3/x^3}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac {8t-\sin 8t}{3t^3}$$ It is $0/0$ form. Apply L-Hospital:
$$L=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8-8 \cos 8t}{9t^2} \implies L=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{64 \sin 8t}{18t} \implies L=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{512 \cos 8 t}{18}=\frac{256}{9} $$